# asp.net core 2.0 - ApplicationUser.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am entering the world of asp.net core (v2.1) and I have been following some tutorials that are on the internet, but I have encountered a problem:
I am learning about roles and users. Through migrations I have created my tables and I have managed to register users with different roles, the next step was through the self-generated interface by the visualstudio itself to show the users and be able to edit, for this I started to investigate and found a tutorial on how to do this. I followed the steps but I found a problem, according to the tutorial I had to add a control with the generated views generated by the visual studio itself and for that I have to add the class model "ApplicationUser.cs" which inherits from "IdentityUser" , here is the problem, that this class does not appear to me. I add a pair of images for better reference.
1
[image]

2
[image]

The first image of the tutorial that I follow, in it appears the class ApplicationUser.cs and second image which is my IDE of development does not appear.

As I was able to investigate, they recommended me to update to a more recent version, which I did but I could not solve the problem

Comment: Have you registered your class in your project's ApplicationDbContext?